# ReactJS unexpected behavior in window event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Stuck on an issue that is probable easy to fix.  I have the following React code (which can be found at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-water-5jjj93?file=/src/App.js:69-613)):

```
export const App = ()=> {
  const [toggle,setToggle] = useState(false);

  const setItemToggle = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.target.tagName==="H1" ? setToggle(!toggle) : setToggle(false)
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("click",setItemToggle,false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click",setItemToggle,false);
  },[])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Current Value Of toggle is {toggle ? "True" : "False"}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you click on the `<h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h>` I expected the toggle to change accordingly; however, it changes once and doesn't toggle after that.  Clicking outside of the element does change the toggle to false.  I know it has to do with the eventListener added to the Window but I can't track it down.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code sandbox is diff than your actual code. Please update link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply changing the state value by doing `setState(!state)`. This pattern does not guarantee that you have the correct value of `state`. You are better off using the functional pattern:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const setItemToggle = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.target.tagName === "H1"
      ? setToggle((toggle) => !toggle)
      : setToggle(false);
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", setItemToggle, false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", setItemToggle, false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Current Value Of toggle is {toggle ? "True" : "False"}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`setState(prevState => !prevState)` is a sure way to ensure you have the correct previous value of state. This is the ideal way to set state when new value of state depends on previous value of state.

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-bush-43cld3?file=/src/App.js:0-667)

The problem is that your function is unaware of the new value of state, one more way to tackle is using the dependancy array. As the name suggests you are defining the dependencies of the your code in the array. Just pass it as the second param to `useEffect` and you should be good to go:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setItemToggle = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.target.tagName === "H1" ? setToggle(!toggle) : setToggle(false);
      e.preventDefault();
    };

    window.addEventListener("click", setItemToggle, false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", setItemToggle, false);
  }, [toggle]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Current Value Of toggle is {toggle ? "True" : "False"}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

We are once again tackling the problem of incorrect state value but this time by rerunning the code inside the `useEffect` callback and hence redefining the function `setItemToggle`.

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-dew-4bpzbu?file=/src/App.js)

Note: Also if a function is only relevant inside `useEffect`, best to define it there only. This is also one of the pros of using `hooks` instead of classes. Your relevant code is in one place.

Answer (score 2):

You have [a stale prop problem](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)

- since the event handler you assign to the event listener is using the initial closure it was created in (so it doesn't see changes to the closed-over `toggle` value),
- and you don't set the function as [a dependency to the `useEffect` invocation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) so a new version of the function never gets used.
  Had you omitted the empty dependency array altogether, this would have worked, with the caveat that you would be continuously re-registering event handlers.

  - I recommend using the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) linter – it would have caught this.

The easy way to fix this is to not close over (refer to) the `toggle` variable at all in the event handler at all by using [the function form of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates): `setToggle(toggle => !toggle)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can just add **onClick** to h1 element and pass a function directly there.

```
<h1 onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
```

some good resource on the topic of Handling Events in react can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) and working sandbox of what I present can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-leftpad-lxnqd2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as OP's code – with OP's code, you can click anywhere in the window.